# Resultset not giving values (not entering in while loop)

Tags: java, android

I have following code in android:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ResultSet rsData)
        {
            try
            {
                int size=0;
                while(rsData.next())
                {
                    size++;
                }
                mlst = new String[size];
                int i=0;
                while(rsData.next())
                {
                    String mid = rsData.getString(rsData.findColumn("mid"));
                    String uid = rsData.getString(rsData.findColumn("uid"));
                    String messages = rsData.getString(rsData.findColumn("message"));                             
                    String read=rsData.getString(rsData.findColumn("rstamp")); 
                    mdb.addMessage(new Contact(mid, uid, messages, read));
                    mlst[i]=mid;
                    i++;
                }
                con.UpdateMessage(mlst);
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

In this i kept debugger on each line.

I found that in first while loop value of size becomes 7.

Means there are 7 rows in rsData ResultSet.

But as soon as it comes on second while loop, it suddenly does not enters in while loop and control directly goes to line : `con.UpdateMessage(mlst);`

I am not able to understand why its happening so?

If resultset has 7 rows in it, then it should enter in it 7 times, but its not entering a single time.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that with

```
while(rsData.next())
{
    size++;
}
```

you move the cursor to the end of the result set. Thus, when you try to run the second while loop, the cursor is already at the end, so the loop is not executed.

You have to set the cursor to the start again, with `rsData.beforeFirst();`. The resulting code should look like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ResultSet rsData)
        {
            try
            {
                int size=0;
                while(rsData.next())
                {
                    size++;
                }
                rsData.beforeFirst();
                mlst = new String[size];
                int i=0;
                while(rsData.next())
                {
                    String mid = rsData.getString(rsData.findColumn("mid"));
                    String uid = rsData.getString(rsData.findColumn("uid"));
                    String messages = rsData.getString(rsData.findColumn("message"));                             
                    String read=rsData.getString(rsData.findColumn("rstamp")); 
                    mdb.addMessage(new Contact(mid, uid, messages, read));
                    mlst[i]=mid;
                    i++;
                }
                con.UpdateMessage(mlst);
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: ohh thanx rsData.first() i was not knowing this

Comment: I made a mistake, it should be `rsData.beforeFirst()` not `first()`, because `next()` gets the next element. If you would write `rsData.first()`, the first element used in the second while loop would be the second element in the result set, not the first.

Comment: its giving me exception null on that statement rsData.beforeFirst()

Comment: NullPointerException or SQLException? Either way, it's weird.

Comment: Sorry, what I was asking was, at which line does the exception occur and what is the type (class) of the exception?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to do

rsData.beforeFirst();

just before the second while loop.

You have gone through the whole result set once and have just passed the last record.  You have not told the ResultSet you want to start another iteration from the beginning again.

Answer (score 2):

[`ResultSet#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) -

> Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. A
>   ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the
>   first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the
>   second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

So you first while loop move the cursor at last row. so at second while loop it is already at last, so it escapes.

You could use `ResultSet#beforeFirst` before second `while-loop` which move your cursor back to normal but It would be better if you use `ArrayList`  insteads of array it dynamically resizable, so no need to care about size, it enhance you code performance.

```
List<String> mlst = new ArrayList<>();
...
mlst.add(mid);
```

Comment: means what should i do to get it on first row?

Comment: how do we move cursor to start again?

Comment: you may use `ResultSet#beforeFirst` it moves the cursor back to normal.

Comment: but it also gives me exception as null on same statement rsData.beforeFirst()

Comment: `ResultSet#beforeFirst` throws `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed result set or the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Comment: while creating `PreparedStatement` pass `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`.

Answer (score 2):

[`rsData.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) changes the cursor position. Calling it twice causes the error.

You can use `List<String>` instead of `String` array so you won't need to get the size  before the data. This way you can use only the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(rsData.next())
{
   size++;
}
```

After this, you're already on the last row of the resultSet. Nothing is next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, while creating the statement:

```
connection.prepareStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```